# jolt shift array up a level, but preserve the array even if empty

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I struggled hard with how to title this one.  This is from the twitter sample stream.  I need the hashtag text pulled out into an array at the top level.   I have that working, but if there is just one hashtag it jolt's to a single string, and if there are no hashtags (twitter gives back an empty array in that case), then the field disappears.  I want to do the same thing with the URL field & user mentions.

Input JSON:

```
{"entities": {
        "hashtags": [{"text": "somethingClever",
                      "indices": [22, 28]},
                     {"text": "somethingLessClever",
                      "indices": [30, 40]}],
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "screen_name": "username",
            "indices": [3, 19]
        }],
        "symbols": []
    }
```

Desired output:

```
{
"hashtags": ["somethingClever"],
              "urls": [],
              "user_mentions": ["username"]
}
```

But what I'm getting is this:
Actual output, note screen_name is not an array and urls is altogether missing.  That is the crux of my problem.

```
{
  "hashtag_text" : [ "somethingClever", "somethingLessClever" ],
  "screen_name" : "username"
}
```

Here is my jolt spec so far:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": { "*": { "text": ".hashtag_text" } },
        "urls": { "*": { "url_text": ".urls" } },
        "user_mentions": { "*": { "screen_name": ".&" } }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.   I used shift to bring the necessary array elements to the next level up (from entities to root).  Next I used the default operation to make it still be an array even if the array was empty.  Lastly, I used the cardinality operation to make it be an array even if there is only one element.

Hopefully this helps somebody.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": { "*": { "text": ".hashtags" } },
        "urls": { "*": { "url_text": ".urls" } },
        "user_mentions": { "*": { "screen_name": ".&" } }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "hashtags[]": {},
      "urls[]": {},
      "screen_name[]": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "hashtags": "MANY",
      "urls": "MANY",
      "screen_name": "MANY"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: 2 years later, it helped me again.